# New to Spring - using sec tag not working

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I'm learning Spring for a project and am trying to teach myself the sec tag for creating multiple views when different users login.  I keep running into errors setting up the tag.

Here is my JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <security:authorize access="hasRole('admin')">
    Only admins can see the <a href="second">Second link</a>
    </security:authorize>
</body>
</html>
```

Which is giving the error: Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"

Here is my xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
    ">



    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter for role checking -->
<bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"/>
    <property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <security:filter-security-metadata-source lowercase-comparisons="true" request-matcher="ant" use-expressions="true">
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/Security/**" access="permitAll"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/Settings/**" access="hasRole('SETTINGS')"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/Home/*" access="hasRole('HOME')"/>              
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/Admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMINISTRATOR')"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/servlet/Download" access="hasAnyRole('DOWNLOAD','PREMIUM_ACCOUNT')"/>

            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator necessary to use <sec:authorized url="xx"> -->
<bean id="webInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator">
    <constructor-arg ref="filterSecurityInterceptor"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

</beans>
```

I've gone back and forth switching "sec" to "security" and a few other things, but can't get it to work.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: search for `Can not find the tag library descriptor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3.release.jar** into your **project's classpath**.

If you are using **Maven**, Add this dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```